# Wordpress echo link to .php, page not found

Tags: php, wordpress

First, I use shortcode API and put these codes inside wp function.php and it works normally. Here the code;

```php
    function example() {
      include('index.php' );
    }

    function examp_func() {
      ob_start();
      example();
      $output = ob_get_contents();
      ob_end_clean();

      return $output;
    }
    add_shortcode( 'example', 'examp_func' );
```

Next, for my index.php file. i created code for a link(i need this hyperlink to execute my create.php file on my index.php page) like this..

```php
  echo "<a href= 'create.php' class='examplecss'>Create New</a>";
```

and when i click on a hyperlink i got page not found. 
I checked url and it's correct. I searched all over the internet and it has yet not found. Any suggestions is really appreciate, thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a space after the `href=` in your link tag. Also are you using SEO urls? If so you might need to link to `/create.php` instead.

Comment: @Geoffrey Thank you for your reply. I'm not use SEO yet. I used both of your solutions and still got "page not found 404". I just want to learn if i can make PHP CRUD from this website [link](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/12/php-and-mysql-crud-tutorial.html) and i got one problem "page not found", and all .php files are inside wp-content/themes/(child folder name). oh, i use cpanel. i wonder which way i went wrong or WP can't directly link to .php? anyway thank you.

Comment: If they are in the theme folder the URL will need to be `/wp-content/themes/(folder)/create.php`, however this is bad practice and you should really write a proper Wordpress Plugin to add you desired functionality.

Comment: yes yes thanks, you right. its work perfectly. I know WP plugin is useful but i need to customize by my own(only this time). again thanks for your suggestion.